# Cross-aggregate projections

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am new to the world of CQRS and event sourcing, trying to evaluate whether it would suite my case. I would appreciate suggestions on how you would do a cross-aggregate projection.

I am thinking about a small specialized Human Resources related service. Candidates submit their resumes, Recruiters submit their vacancies. Commanded and CQRS should work just fine for whichever slices and dices I'd want to have e.g. for listing the highest paying vacancies in a particular field.

But I can't wrap my head about recommendations. If I have a primitive recommendation engine to recommend candidates with `elixir` skill to recruiters looking for `elixir` skill and the other way around, does it essentially mean that I need to build a projection (a PostgreSQL table most probably) on every vacancy/candidate update? Possibly even rebuild the whole table on every small aggregate change?

- Is it normal and expected or am I missing something?
- Or is it conceptually okay to have separate projections for candidates/recruiters and "derive" recommendations by querying them with an sql JOIN? Even if recommendations will become more computationally intensive later (e.g. require calling a machine leaning mode)?
- Or is it a known problem with the known recommendations?
- How would you do it? I will be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more general things you can do is to project events relating to what developers have a given skill and what recruiters are looking for a given skill into a per-skill event stream (e.g. "developer A knows elixir", "recruiter Z needs elixir").

A consumer of that stream could update a table optimized for the "give me the developers and recruiters where there's a match" like

```
skill STRING,
user STRING,
user_type ENUM of "developer", "recruiter",
PRIMARY KEY (skill, user)  ;; could trivially shard this by skill
```

...but a consumer could also do something like use a document store to persist the list of developers and recruiters that are possible matches for the skill, or an ML algorithm could consume the events and do whatever.